# Django Rest Framework Nested Relationships Displays ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Basically I have a receipt that has a Vendor, and Location associated with it. I would like the HTTP `get` requests to return the associations as nested models. Following the documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) to create the serializers does not get the expected result.

```
python: 3.9.1
django: 3.2.3
djangorestframework: 3.12.4
```

### models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Vendor(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.description


class VendorLocation(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(
        Vendor,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='locations',
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.description


class Receipt(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(
        Vendor,
        blank=True, null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='receipts',
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        VendorLocation,
        blank=True, null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='receipts',
    )
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

### serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Vendor, VendorLocation, Receipt


class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = '__all__'


class VendorLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VendorLocation
        fields = '__all__'


class ReceiptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vendor: VendorSerializer(many=False)
    location: VendorLocationSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Receipt
        fields = [
            'datetime', 'subtotal', 'tax', 'amount',
            'vendor', 'location', 
        ]
```

### views.py

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Receipt
from .serializers import ReceiptSerializer

class ReceiptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Receipt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReceiptSerializer
```

### urls.py

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import ReceiptViewSet

router.register('receipt', viewset=ReceiptViewSet)
```

## Result

The response is

```json
{
    "datetime": "2020-11-27T21:13:00Z",
    "subtotal": null,
    "tax": null,
    "amount": "114.02",
    "vendor": 2,
    "location": 16,
}
```

I am expecting it to be.

```json
{
    "datetime": "2020-11-27T21:13:00Z",
    "subtotal": null,
    "tax": null,
    "amount": "114.02",
    "vendor": {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "Test Vendor 2",
    },
    "location": {
        "id": 16,
        "description": "123 Main Street",
        "vendor": 2,
    }
}
```

I've tried reloading and restarting the server, changing or adding `read_only`, `many`, `source` parameters in the `VendorSerializer` and `VendorLocationSerializer`, and adding or removing the fields from the `Meta` class attribute.

Comment: Django REST Framework does not support the type hints syntax for defining fields. You've probably meant to use `=` instead of `:`, as you do in the Django model definitions.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just so used to type hints I didn't even think about that!